# Is there a way to run scripted commands under gdb coredump inspection?

Tags: c++, shell, gdb

I always use the same set of commands opening GDB:

```
gdb -c dump
gdb>symbol-file libsmth.so
gdb>sharedlibrary
gdb>bt
```

It always takes a minute to type it, wait for execution, and answer the couple of `--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--` messages. I want to cut this inspection time to the a minimum.

How can I tell gdb to always `continue without paging`?

How can I put the 3 lines I am executing into an `.sh` sort of script and run them every time?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gdbinit.5.html

Comment: `gdb --command=FILE -c dump`

Answer (score 1):

```
gdb -ex 'set height 0' -ex 'where' libsmth.so dump
```

The `sharedlibrary` command you are using shouldn't be necessary, unless you've disabled loading of shared library symbols in your `.gdbinit` (which is doubtful, since you appear to be unaware that GDB can be customized via `.gdbinit`).